# Prove that the eigenvalues of a product of positive semidefinite matrices are nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

> Show that if $A,B \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are positive semidefinite and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ then $\lambda \geq 0$.

I don't really know what to do here. If $AB$ was semidefinite positive we would be done but the product of positive semidefinite matrices doesn't have to be positive semidefinite itself.

Comment: are $A,B$ symmetric ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi no they are not.

Comment: @Yagger Usually, "positive semidefinite" implies symmetric.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi they are symetric

Comment: I suspected @Yagger .. I have posted an answer when they are symmetric using square roots of matrices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ABx = \lambda x$, $x\neq 0$, then $\langle ABx,Bx\rangle = \lambda \langle x,Bx\rangle$. Now, both $\langle ABx,Bx\rangle$ and $\langle x,Bx\rangle$ are non-negative. Hence, if $\langle x,Bx\rangle > 0$, it follows that $\lambda\ge 0$. If $\langle x,Bx\rangle = 0$, then $Bx = 0$ and thus $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: For OP's sake, this also holds if you expand the definition of positive-semidefinite to non-symmetric matrices, as $x^TBx\geq 0\Leftrightarrow x^TB^Tx\geq 0$.

Comment: I agree with @AlexR. (+1 Alex) 
Btw, you got me cracking "For OP's sake.."

Comment: @Alex: But what if $\langle ABx,Bx\rangle = \langle Bx,x\rangle = 0$? Then $\lambda$ can be anything.

Comment: I misread the problem, the are symmetric. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive semidefinite real symmetric matrices.
Denote $\sqrt{A}$ the square root of $A$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 A = \sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}
\end{equation}
where $\sqrt{A}$ is also PSD.
Notice that $$\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}$$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite. Also, $$AB = \sqrt{A}(\sqrt{A} B)$$ and $$(\sqrt{A}B)\sqrt{A}$$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: That's an original approach! +1